# Help identify or find more examples of this font

Tags: font-identification, typefaces, book, lettering, character-styles

I am attempting to either "revive" or find a particular font for a project, but seeing as I found it in an old book, I have only been able to find a few examples of its usage. Using the examples below, would any of you happen to know the name for it or point me to some other books or documents where it was used? As a clue, I found it in a book published in Geelong, Australia in the late 1800's.

I use Photoshop to remove characters from the texts, so more examples are really all I need.

Thanks!

[image: baronmueller]

[image: islands]

Comment: Note: you can comment on my answer to give feedback and/or you can mark it as "accepted." It looks like you signed up twice: your question and your "answer as comment" are from two separate unregistered accounts.

Answer (score 7):

Out of curiosity, I looked at the book in question to see if there was colophon information. Some books include the typeface names used. This one did not.

Then I did a search for 19th century free ebooks with type specimens and found one called *Shniedewend & Lee Co's specimen book and price list of type*, Shniedewend & Lee Co, Mackellar, Smiths & Jordan (1873) ( [link](http://books.google.com/books?id=5XpQAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA208&dq=1873%20type%20specimen%20book&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iU2CUuDUMI_dsAStiIFo&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=1873%20type%20specimen%20book&f=false) ). Most (read: all) publishers/printers use(d) manufactured typefaces and in the 1870s, specimen books were the way they picked and purchased them.

On page 174 I see a specimen labeled "English Monastic" which is pretty close.

It looks like someone made a "free for personal use" font named "K22 Monastic" which is based upon this or one like it ( [link](http://www.dafont.com/k22-monastic.font?text=Hebrides,%20Loyalty%20Islands) )

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! You are an excellent internet investigator. :) The fact that there is one to download is even better than I was expecting! It'll save me a ton of work... It is helpful to see the related "monastic" type specimens, as well. Thanks again! (Sorry, I was unsure of how to reply directly to your answer.)

Comment: And if a true lower-case is required, it looks like Bookman would be a good match.

Comment: PierreC. if @horatio gave you the right answer, please click "accept answer". This is good for you, him and all the rest of us.